# How to implement an own QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I am trying to understand the way a [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) is working to implement my own `MyQScrollArea` widget. `MyQScrollArea` should make use of [setViewportMargins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins). For this I wrote a minimum working example shown below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class MyScrollArea(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(", ".join(map(str, range(100))), self)

        hScrollBar = self.horizontalScrollBar()

        hScrollBar.setRange(0, self.label.sizeHint().width() - self.sizeHint().width())
        hScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(self._HScrollBarValueChanged)

        self.setViewportMargins(100, 0, 0, 0)
        self._HScrollBarValueChanged(0)

    def _HScrollBarValueChanged(self, value):
        self.label.move(-value + self.viewportMargins().left(), 0)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scroll = MyScrollArea()
    scroll.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The result of the code is shown below:

[image: Widget before scrolling]

However, after I scroll the inner widget moves out of the viewport and paints itself in an area I do not want it to be painted:

[image: Widget after scrolling]

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the [setViewportMargins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins) functionality working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it the QLabel as a child of the viewport, in addition to modifying the properties of the QScrollBar every time the geometry of the widgets is modified:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyScrollArea(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(", ".join(map(str, range(100))), self.viewport())

        self.setViewportMargins(100, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.on_hscrollbar_value_changed
        )
        self.update_scrollbar()

    def on_hscrollbar_value_changed(self, value):
        self.label.move(-value, 0)

    def update_scrollbar(self):
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setRange(
            0, self.label.sizeHint().width() - self.viewport().width()
        )
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setPageStep(self.viewport().width())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.update_scrollbar()
        super().resizeEvent(event)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scroll = MyScrollArea()
    scroll.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You don't know how many things I tried, but I did't try setting the viewport as a parent. Thx for pointing that out. The rest of the missing code is due to the minimum working example. Thx for your help!